# using for loop to input multiple data

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to programming. Here is my dilemma. I have to replace multiple files in multiple locations across multiple computers.

I have written a bat script where I am defining all the variables and calling a txt file with appropriate information. For example -testing.txt has the values

```
Apple, Potato,Beef
Apple, Potato,Pork
```

The logic I am applying is as follows: I am using this txt file for reading and then going to each location to change the file

```
set Path=%Path%;c:\Tools\UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin
SET SORC=C:\tools\logosource\NEWImages\ApiSite\Content

for /F "usebackq delims=, tokens=1-3" %%a in (C:\tools\xxxx\testing.txt) do (
SET HOSTNAME=%%a
SET CUSTNAME=%%c
SET STYPE=%%b
SET DEST=\\%HOSTNAME%\c$\Documents and Settings\blahblah\My    Documents\%CUSTNAME%\%STYPE%\goodman\

echo HOSTNAME is %HOSTNAME%
echo CUSTNAME is %CUSTNAME%
echo STYPE is %STYPE%
echo DEST is %DEST%
echo SORC is %SORC%
 )

 copy "%DEST%\ApiSite\Content\images\michael.gif" "%DEST%"
 copy /b /y "%SORC%\images\george.gif" "%DEST%\ApiSite\Content\images\michael.gif"


goto End

:Error

ECHO Error! You must pass in a servername
goto End

:End
```

The problem is that my loop is only reading the last line my txt file. ie. it reads "Apple, Potato,Pork" and sets the DEST TO THAT VALUE.

What i really want is to read line 1 (Apple, Potato,Beef) set the DEST using these parameters and change the files, then go back and read the second line (Apple, Potato,Pork) and set the DEST using these parameters and change the files.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is reading every line in the file, but your logic is wrong.

Your main problem is you want to do the COPY statements for each line, but you have the COPY statements outside the loop. Of course they will only get executed once, and the values used will be the values that were set by the last line in the file. The solution is to move the COPY statements inside the loop.

Your other problem is you are attempting to set a variable within a parenthesized block, and then access the value using `%var%` - that cannot work because the expansion occurs when the statement is parsed and the entire block is parsed once before any lines are read. You could solve that problem by using delayed expansion, (type `HELP SET` from the command line prompt for more information about delayed expansion). But there really isn't any need to save the values in variables. Simply use the FOR variables directly. Because the DEST is used multiple times, I used an additional FOR loop to define a `%%d` variable that contains the DEST value. The `~` removes the quotes that the FOR loop added.

Also, you are ending the script by using `GOTO END` and defining an `:END` label at the end of file. That works, but there is an implicit `:EOF` label at the end of every script. You can simply use `GOTO :EOF` without defining a label. The other option is to use `EXIT /B`

You have an `:ERROR` routine that is not being called - I presume you have additional code that you are not showing.

```
set Path=%Path%;c:\Tools\UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin
SET "SORC=C:\tools\logosource\NEWImages\ApiSite\Content"

for /F "usebackq delims=, tokens=1-3" %%a in (C:\tools\xxxx\testing.txt) do (
  for %%d in (
    "\\%%a\c$\Documents and Settings\blahblah\My Documents\%%b\%%b\goodman\"
  ) do (
    echo HOSTNAME=%%a
    echo CUSTNAME=%%c
    echo STYPE=%%b
    echo DEST=%%~d
    echo SORC is %SORC%
    copy "%%~d\ApiSite\Content\images\michael.gif" "%%~d"
    copy /b /y "%SORC%\images\george.gif" "%%~d\ApiSite\Content\images\michael.gif"
  )
)
exit /b

:Error
ECHO Error! You must pass in a servername
exit /b
```